# Can't run GCP VM on public IP with SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, virtual-machine

I am setting up a Virtual Machine node.js server at Google Cloud Platform. I have set up SSH keys so that I can log into my VM. I can successfully log into my VM using SSH-in-browser and start my server.

I can't access my public IP address through Chrome. I get this message:
`This site can’t provide a secure connection`.

When I try to connect to the IP within SSH-in-browser, I get the following:

```
$ curl -vso /dev/null --connect-timeout 5 34.68.254.120:8080
*   Trying 34.68.254.120:8080...
* connect to 34.68.254.120 port 8080 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 34.68.254.120 port 8080: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
```

I'm new at this. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit1: Some more details --

- Linux VM
- port 8080 ingress is open on the firewall
- I'm using OSLogin (`enable-oslogin = TRUE' 'enable-oslogin-sk = FALSE')
- I can successfully log into console with both SSH-in-Browser and PuTTY, and I can start my server on port 8080
- In both, I get the error above when I try to connect to the IP address

Comment: You've configured you're site to listen on secure port and I think without a certificate. Please add more details of how you're configuring your app. Also, are you sure something is listening on port 8080 or that the firewall rules allow connections on that port?

Comment: My app is listening on port 8080, and my firewall has ingress to 8080. I saw somewhere that my firewall has to allow ingress and egress to three specific google sites, perhaps that is the problem? It appears my MongoDB connection is working (port 27017), so that's a good sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

**Follow below steps to fix “This Site Can’t Provide a Secure Connection” Error :**

This error typically indicates a problem with either [your browser’s configuration or the SSL certificate on your site](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/mamp-this-site-cant-provide-a-secure-connection/).

> **1) Your local environment doesn’t have an SSL certificate.**
>
> **2) Outdated SSL caches in the browser :** (*This is one of the more popular causes.* Web browsers store SSL certificates in a cache, much
> like other data. This means they don’t have to verify the certificate
> every time you visit a site, which speeds up browsing. However, if
> your SSL certificate changes and the browser is still loading an
> older, cached version, it can cause this error to pop up).
>
> **3) Incorrect time and date settings on your computer.**
>
> **4) Rogue browser extensions.**
>
> **5) Overzealous antivirus software.**
>
> **6) An invalid or expired SSL certificate.**

**If your  firewall rules prevent external access:**

> Check your firewall rules with the following command: `gcloud compute firewall-rules list` with this, you can review the VPC where
> the VM instance was migrated; and if it has allowed the Ingress TCP:
> 22 Port.
> If this firewall rule is missing, you can add the firewall rule in the **GCP console -> VPC Networks ->select your VPC network _Click on
> the firewall** rules to double check that the tcp: 22 port is allowed.
>
> If the issue still is ongoing after checking the firewall rules, you
> can follow this guide to start [troubleshooting SSH connection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh#run_the_troubleshooting_tool).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I have port 22 open. I'm able to log into my VM instance through SSH-in-Browser (and Cloud Shell, incidentally). I can start my server. However, I'm not able to access the IP through Chrome. Could it be this line in the documentation? I have done nothing to allow these domains, and I'm not sure exactly how to. `The network must allow traffic to and from hostnames ending in google.com, gstatic.com, or googleapis.com.`

Comment: I also have OSLogin enabled (`enable-oslogin` and `enable-oslogin-sk`) but have some remaining SSH keys listed in my metadata. Should I delete those as OSLogin takes care of the keys itself (I think)?

Comment: Yes, By default, Compute Engine uses custom project and/or instance metadata to configure SSH keys and to manage SSH access. All Windows VMs use metadata to manage SSH keys (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/ssh#metadata), while Linux VMs can use metadata keys or OS Login. If you use OS Login, metadata SSH keys are disabled.

Comment: What does it actually mean that I can access my server through SSH/PuTTY and run my code, but I get `This site can't provide a secure connection; 34.68.254.120 sent an invalid response` when I try to access the external IP through Chrome?

Comment: Try this link (https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/mamp-this-site-cant-provide-a-secure-connection/)

Comment: Oh jeez, it was indeed a simple cache clearing. Thank you for the help, Veera!